# How to find control characters for reading a large text file?

Tags: .net, xml, streamreader

Problem:  I have a very large (300MB+) text file that has some interesting formatting using STX and ETX control characters. Example:

```
plain txt infoSTX<xml ..xml message data.. /xml>ETX
```

There are hundreds, if not thousands, of what I would refer to as 'blocks' of xml messages, each encapsulated between STX and ETX control characters.  These messages can span multiple lines, not just each on a single line.

As I parse the file, I need to be able to locate each of the xml blocks for individual parsing.

I assume that a simple buffered stream reader would work here but I need to be able to keep track of where I am reading to pull out each individual xml block between the control characters until I reach the end of the file.

I think I can read the file using this simple method:

```
while (sr.Read(buffer, index, count) > 0) 
{ 
/*
  read my xml and parse, etc
*/
}
```

But how do I set my indexes (start/finish) for reading when dealing with these STX and ETX control characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.txt";

        enum State
        {
            FIND_STX,
            READ_DATA
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char STX = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0x02 }).First();
            char ETX = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0x03 }).First();

            string testMessage = string.Format("plain txt info{0}<xml ..xml message data.. /xml>{1}", STX, ETX);

            StreamReader reader = null;
            StreamWriter writer = null;

            //write test output file
            writer = new StreamWriter(INPUT_FILENAME, false, Encoding.UTF8);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(testMessage);
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            //now read test file
            reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);
            writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILENAME, false, Encoding.UTF8);

            char[] newChar = new char[1];
            State state = State.FIND_STX;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                reader.Read(newChar, 0, 1);
                switch (state)
                {
                    case State.FIND_STX :
                        if (newChar[0] == STX)
                        {
                            state = State.READ_DATA;
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.READ_DATA :
                        if (newChar[0] == ETX)
                        {
                            state = State.FIND_STX;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.Write(newChar[0]);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some VB, this is what I've come up with so far, which is working but seems pretty inefficient.

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(dataFile)
Dim line As String = ""
Dim text As String = ""

While sr.Peek > -1

    line = sr.ReadLine
    Dim startPos = line.IndexOf(Chr(2)) + 1
    Dim isTrue As Boolean = True
    While isTrue
        'if line contains ETX, get its position else just keep reading
         Dim endPos = line.IndexOf(Chr(3))
         If endPos = -1 Then
              text += line.Substring(startPos)
              line = sr.ReadLine
              startPos = 0
         Else                            
              text += line.Substring(startPos, line.LastIndexOf(Chr(3)))
              isTrue = False
         End If
    End While
    'do something with the text here then reset text and keep going
    text = ""

End While
```

This actually sets "text" to be one complete xml message, which is what I am looking for but I am wondering if this is efficient enough for a very large file.

Comment: Surprisingly it only takes about 4 seconds to read a 200MB file and report back on the number of xml messages it contains.  In this case over 225k of them.  Of course I'll still need to parse each of those messages and handle the data but this seems to work.  Probably needs a lot of error handling and all that kind of thing.  Any other suggestions would be great.